# Pandas count values in one column where another column stays the same

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to get a count of all values in one column where another column stays the same.. having a real brain fart here. Below is an example since I know the wording is kind of weird to read.

Data:

```
a | item1
a | item2
a | item3
a | item4
b | item1
b | item3
c | item4
```

What I am trying to achieve:

```
a | item1 | 4
a | item2 | 4 
a | item3 | 4
a | item4 | 4
b | item1 | 2
b | item3 | 2
c | item4 | 1
```

I've tried a few different ways of doing this but keep ending up with some really weird count numbers. Also, my end goal is to have this data all consolidated to an excel sheet. I currently have a fairly large sheet with a bunch of columns, but I can't figure out how to get this count.

That being said, since it is already in excel and the end goal is excel, I would be fine with a solution there too. Just figured Pandas would likely be faster and easier than writing an excel function of some kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby()` with `transform`:

```
df['col_3'] = df.groupby('col_1')['col_2'].transform('count')
```

Output:

```
  col_1 col_2   col_3
0     a     1       4
1     a     2       4
2     a     3       4
3     a     4       4
4     b     1       2
5     b     3       2
6     c     4       1
```

Example data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':['a','a','a','a','b','b','c'],
                   'col_2':[1,2,3,4,1,3,4]})
```

Comment: Ah perfect! Thank you! This was exactly what I needed but for some reason, transform completely eluded my brain. Will mark as the answer. :)

Comment: Cheers! Yes I used to always forget about `transform`, but a very powerful tool! Thanks!

Comment: Why do you add ['col_2'] in the groupby? the output is the same without it.

Comment: Yeah, it's unnecessary, my bad. For whatever reason what thinking of `value_counts`